# Shopify Custom Shipping Script - How can I combine 2 scripts?

Tags: ruby, shopify, shipping-method

I have two scripts, and it works wonderfully. In Shopify only one script can be published in one section in the script editor. 
How can i make a working script out of it?

A script for sorting the shipping solution

```
desired_order = ["DHL","TM Logistik (DHL)","Chronopost","FedEx","DPD","FedEx Express","DPD Express"]

Output.shipping_rates = Input.shipping_rates.sort_by do |shipping_rate|
desired_order.index(shipping_rate.name) || desired_order.length
end
```

and a second script to hide the shipping solution when entering a Packstation in the address field

```
shippingaddress1 = Input.cart.shipping_address.address1.upcase.split[0...-1].join ' '
checkpobox = ['PACKSTATION','POSTFILIALE','PACK','POST']
puts shippingaddress1
if checkpobox.include?(shippingaddress1)
  hideship = ['DPD','Chronopost','DPD Express','FedEx','FedEx Express']
else
  hideship = ['NO DPD']
end

Output.shipping_rates = Input.shipping_rates.delete_if do |shipping_rate|
  hideship.any? { |hideship| shipping_rate.name.include?(hideship) }
end
```

How can I combine them?

Could anyone help?

Is it also possible to include a query that if "checkpobox" has something entered like 'PACKSTATION','POSTFILIALE', then the field "Optional address2 label" is a required field?

Thanks a lot